# ndb design many-to-many with parent child change

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling, app-engine-ndb

after a lot of research here and lots of reading [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) for me is still not clear in some cases how parent and child works:

```
 +------------------------+                                    +------------------------+
 | Room Model             |           +----------------+       | Room Model             |
 |                        <-----------+                +------->                        |
 +--+----------------+----+           |  Supporter     |       +------------------------+
    |                |                +----------------+          |                |
    |         +------v-----+                                      |         +------v-----+
    |         |            |                                      |         |            |
    |         | customer   |                                      |         | customer   |
    |         |            |                                      |         |            |
    |         +--+---------+                                      |         +--+---------+
    |            |                                                |            |
    |            |                                                |            |
 +--v+-----------v-+                                           +--v+-----------v-+
 |                 |                                           |                 |
 |   Device        |                                           |   Device        |
 |                 |                                           |                 |
 +---+-----------+-+                                           +---+-----------+-+
     |           |                                                 |           |
     |           |                                                 |           |
     |     +-----v------------+                                    |     +-----v------------+
     |     |                  |                                    |     |                  |
     |     | Issues / tickets |                                    |     | Issues / tickets |
     |     +------------------+                                    |     +------------------+
     |                                                             |
    +v---------------+  +--------+                                +v---------------+  +--------+
    | pdf / pics     |  |Blob_key|                                | pdf / pics     |  |Blob_key|
    |                |  |        |                                |                |  |        |
    +----------------+-->--------+                                +----------------+-->--------+
```

Here is my situation:

I have different rooms and the room ,model are the highest entity in the relationship, it does not change, but all the childs connected to it changes and some of them have more childs. So a room can have several customers at the same time and several devices which 1- some belong to the room and 2- some were allocated to the room:

```
class Room(MainModel):
  # room_number is ID or key of room which is the parent of all entities
  room_number = ndb.StringProperty()
  # I don't know if this is the correct way to do this.
  devices = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Device', repeated=True)
  # maybe this should be in the Device model?
  devices_allocated = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Device.allocation', repeated=True)
  based_supporters = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Supporter')
  supporter = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Supporter')
  customers = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Customers', repeated="True")
  # Or should I go for ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Issue', repeated="True")?
  issues = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Vehicle.issues', repeated="True")
```

Then I have supporters which takes care of the rooms contents(customers and devices) they can support more than 1 room and and consequently several customers and devices(childs of the rooms) and have have one base room, means they are sitting in a room monitoring other rooms...

```
class Supporter(MainModel):
          # id is ID or key of supporter which is child of room but becomes child of another room if changed
          id = ndb.StringProperty()
          name = ndb.StringProperty()
          #I wonder if is possible to get these entities from the room model... Like this
          devices = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Room.devices', repeated=True)
          customers = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Customer', repeated=True)
          #room which supporter stays
          base_room = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Room')
          #rooms which supporter supports
          rooms = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Room', repeated="True")
```

Then I have customers, which are in a room(parent) and can use a device(child of the room) which should be able to be replaced depending on the situation, customers can change rooms and therefore the device of the room:

```
class Customer(MainModel):
      # id is ID or key of customer which is child of room but becomes child of another room if changed
      id = ndb.StringProperty()
      name = ndb.StringProperty()
      # device customer is using which can change
      device = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Device')
      supporter = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Supporter')
      #customer room which can change
      room = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Room')
```

Then I have the devices which are always in a room(parent) or going to another room(parent change) the devices have files, pics(children of device) which moves with the device and it gets to another room, exception of the issue(child of the device and indirect child of the room)  which belongs to the device but should show the room number it was created.

```
class Device(MainModel):
          # id is ID or key of device which is child of room but becomes child of another room if changed
          id = ndb.StringProperty()
          name = ndb.StringProperty()
          customer = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Customer')
          supporter = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Supporter')
          # device base room
          base_room =  ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Room')
          # device actual room which can change 
          room = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Room')
          issue = ndb.KeyProperty(kind="issue", repeated="True")
          file = ndb.KeyProperty(kind="File", repeated="True")
          pics = ndb.KeyProperty(kind="Pics", repeated="True")
```

Finally I have issues and tickets from the devices(parent of the tickets and issues)

```
class Issue(MainModel):
              # id is ID or key of issue which is child of device
              id = ndb.StringProperty()
              title = ndb.StringProperty()
              # This is the parent of the issue model
              device = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='device')
              # place the issue were created
              room = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Room')
              # issue child's attachments not the same as device attachments
              file = ndb.KeyProperty(kind="File", repeated="True")
              pics = ndb.KeyProperty(kind="Pics", repeated="True")
```

Is this the correct way to apply the key property? looks very confusion to me... specially in this complex relationship design model
what are you thinking? I there another way of doing this? How would be the best or more efficient approach to change parent or child or both dynamically?

I will try it an I will keep updating here, please feel free to share opinion why and how could be better or not.

Regards

Comment: for complex structured data, its best to use SQL instead of datastore which is based on NoSQL schema.

Comment: ^^ this is not appropriate advice.  you can structure this in NoSQL and make it work just fine... it just takes a little more work

Comment: I also noticed that when using **structuredProperty** it complains when there is "repeated=true" direct or indirectly